# UTF-8 error with verbments

Tags: pdftex, unicode, verbments

I'm writing a book using Latex in what I want to write code in Python. My operating system is Linux and my editor is Kile with:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verbments}
```

But I can not see the characters in Spanish

```
\begin{pyglist}[language = python, encoding = utf8]
    print ('Tomorrow is another day')
\end{pyglist}
```

I perform the compilation with the command

```
pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction = nonstopmode
```

but I get the following error.

```
*** Error while highlighting:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can not decode byte 0xf1 in position 9: invalid continuation byte
    (file "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pygments/lexer.py", line 164, in get_tokens)
```

I also have observed that verbments generates a file called name.pyg.sty that curiously is codified in ISO-8859-15 instead of UTF-8 as all my other files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`verbments`, like `minted` and `pythontex`, uses `fancyvrb` behind the scenes.  `pythontex` patches `fancyvrb` to support Unicode, as does the [development version](https://github.com/gpoore/minted) of `minted` (but not the version on CTAN).  You can use `pythontex` or the development version of `minted`.  Or you can just copy over the `fancyvrb` patch.  Basically, when `fancyvrb` writes the code to a temp file, it needs to `\detokenize` everything so that Unicode works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verbments}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\verbments@write@detok}[1]{%
  \immediate\write\FV@OutFile{\detokenize{#1}}}
\newcommand{\verbments@FVB@VerbatimOut}[1]{%
  \@bsphack
  \begingroup
  \FV@UseKeyValues
  \FV@DefineWhiteSpace
  \def\FV@Space{\space}%
  \FV@DefineTabOut
  \let\FV@ProcessLine\verbments@write@detok
  \immediate\openout\FV@OutFile #1\relax
  \let\FV@FontScanPrep\relax
  \let\@noligs\relax
  \FV@Scan}
\let\FVB@VerbatimOut\verbments@FVB@VerbatimOut
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{pyglist}[language = python]
    print('Tomorrow is another day é ñ')
\end{pyglist}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems you have solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I've not been able to compile successfully with either `verbments` or `minted`. However, if you have a fairly recent TeX distribution, `pythontex` works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pythontex}

\begin{document}
\begin{pygments}{python}
    print ('Tomorrow is another day é ñ')
\end{pygments}
\end{document}
```

You have to run `pdflatex` and then `pythontex` over the main file. Another run of `pdflatex` will include the formatted listing.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, your suggestion works, but I prefer to patch the verbments package.

Answer (score 0):

I had no luck with `verbments` on `pdflatex`. The error message was very close to the one seen by the original poster. Also an ISO 8859-1(5) coded `<name>.pyg.lst` file was generated.

Changing the compiler to `lualatex --shell-escape` worked fine with the following document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage{verbments}

\begin{document}
\begin{pyglist}[language = python, encoding = utf8]
    print ('Tomorrow is another day é ñ')
\end{pyglist}
\end{document}
```

[image: Pretty-printed python code]